# Scriptlets inserts arbitrary code into servlet's _jspService method

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, scriptlet

> **Scriptlets let you insert arbitrary code into servlet's _jspService method.**

Can anyone explain this statement with an example containing a block of code?

I am aware about syntactical stuff of JSP and Servlets, what I need to know is

- In what context **arbitrary code** is used?

_jspService() is a method of JSP life cycle then,

- What does it mean by **servlet's method**?

Comment: All you need to worry about is *never use scriptlets*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSP is in fact transformed by the container into a Java class extending HttpServlet, that class is then compiled and executed exactly as a hand-coded servlet would be.

The code you have into the JSP is transformed into Java code that constitutes the _jspService method of the generated servlet. So, for example

```
<html>
<% String foo = "hello"; out.println(foo); %>
```

is transformed by the container, into something like

```
void _jspService(JspWriter out) {
    out.println("<html>");
    String foo = "hello"; out.println(foo);
}
```

So, whatever code you write into your scriptlets (*arbitrary code*) ends up in the _jspService method of the servlet created by the container from the JSP.