# Spoon and JDT like code parsing tool for JSP scriplets?

Tags: jsp, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt, spoon, inria-spoon

I have used Eclipse JDT API for analysing and processing Java codes of several Java classes by making AST tree of code. I have also used Spoon code parsing tool for one of my projects and successfully processed Java class files.

Is there any similar tool available for JSP files ? I want to parse, analyse and possible modify the code automatically.

Please suggest what I can use to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite familiar with JSP, but looking on the web I found that scriptlets are compiled in a java class extending HttpServlet (see: [Scriptlets inserts arbitrary code into servlet's _jspService method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32679523/scriptlets-inserts-arbitrary-code-into-servlets-jspservice-method/32680065)). Then I assume, you can use jspc (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-0790/6nlqo2pgh/index.html) to obtain the Java file corresponding to your JSP and then use Spoon or JDT on it.